# When sending a DELETE query, does innoDB delete data from database one-by-one, or first create a list of data to be deleted?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a database table with ~140,000 rows, and right now I am doing a query that goes like

```
DELETE FROM database WHERE type="delete"
```

But it is taking a long time. I am tempted to halt the query and see if the database has actually shrunken in size, but I am not sure if it's in the process of creating a list of data to be deleted before the data actually gets removed. How does innoDB actually clear out data from the database upon receiving a DELETE query?

Here is the CREATE query (for the table `images`):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `images` (
  `imageID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `runID_fk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sequenceID_fk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cameraID_fk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` longblob,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `name` text,
  `type` text,
  `pcadata` longblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`imageID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Please post the table definition (the `CREATE` statement). Have you tried an `EXPLAIN` query, as in `EXPLAIN DELETE FROM database WHERE type="delete"`? Also, do you have an index on the `type` column? If you are deleting a very large percentage of the data, it might make more sense to create a temporary table, copy over only data you want to keep, and replace the existing one.

Comment: @EdCottrell, wouldn't the query for copying over data take just as much time?

Comment: That depends. Like I said, if you want to delete "a very larger percentage of the data," that approach can be faster. Imagine if you were trying to delete 139,999 of 140,000 rows. Copying one row and deleting the entire old table would be much faster than deleting 139,999 rows.

Comment: I understand, but it would take some time for the database to look for that single image with the right parameter, no?

Comment: Of course; all queries take *some* time. But the issue in that case wouldn't be the time required to find the relevant row(s); it would be the time required to delete all of the data and update all relevant indexes, check all relevant constraints, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your `CREATE` statement, you do not have an index on the `type` column. So, your problem is due to a slow `WHERE` clause. Basically, your query is forcing the database server to look at each and every row to see if value in the `type` column is `"delete"`. That is slow, no matter how many rows you have. An index would make this much faster because the server could essentially just ask for a list of all matching rows, then only operate on those rows.

As a very broad rule of thumb, if you intend to use a column in a `WHERE` clause, it should be indexed. (There are exceptions, for sure, but this is not one of them based on what you've posted.)

You can see what the database server is doing by running an `EXPLAIN` query, as in

```
EXPLAIN DELETE FROM database WHERE type="delete"
```

---

Based on your comment, your `EXPLAIN` returns something like this:

```
id   select_type   table    partitions   type   possible_keys   key     key_len   ref    rows     filtered  Extra
1    SIMPLE        images                ALL    null            null    null      null   145669             Using where
```

That 145,699 that you see is not (as you wrote in the comment) "the size of the rows." It's the number of rows that the server has to look at to execute your query. As you can see, it doesn't have any indexes it can use. So, instead of looking at only the rows you want to delete, it has to look at 145,669 rows.

Also, since your `type` column is a `TEXT` column, this will be even slower. You should seriously consider adding a `TINYINT`, `CHAR` (not `TEXT`), or other column to store the status of the row if you intend to flag rows for deletion this way.

On a more general note, you really should reconsider some of those column types. I seriously doubt that you need `2^16 - 1` bytes for a column named `name`, for example.

Comment: I just did the EXPLAIN query, and it says "1 SIMPLE images  ALL  null null null null 145669 Using where". The large number is the size of the rows, but I am not sure what this actually means.

Comment: Now I understand the issue better. In my self-defense, I wasn't the one who set up the database this way....

Comment: I understand; sometimes we're stuck with others' bad designs! Just a heads-up for future reference. Thanks for accepting!

Comment: I just found out that finding imageID for deletion instead of doing a direct DELETE query is much, much faster. If I can somehow pipeline the query result (list of ImageID to be deleted) to the DELETE query then, I assume it will be faster as well.

Comment: Yes, anything that uses an index will be faster. Because your primary key uses `imageID`, a query based on `imageID` values will be very fast.

Comment: @EdCottrell - Faster, yes.  "Very fast"; not with that many rows.

Comment: @RickJames I meant very fast *relatively*, of course.

Answer (score 1):

- `INDEX` was already mentioned.
- `TEXT` columns (of which have 4) may be stored elsewhere, necessitating an extra disk hit.  (already mentioned).
- InnoDB builds a list of things to undo in case of a crash; this is possibly the biggest cost.
- Deleting in chunks of no more than 1000 rows is a better idea.  Walk through the `PRIMARY KEY` to find the chunks.
- There are other techniques if this is a recurring task.
- If deleting more than, say, half the table, then:  Create new table; `INSERT SELECT` to copy the keepers; `RENAME TABLE` to swap; `DROP`.

See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig) for details on the last three suggestions.

Comment: I eventually tried a code where I query a list of primary key values whose matching rows have the right column value (so I select ~3500 out of ~140,000) and then back them up using dump, and drop the entire database. I added the option ( where=”imageID IN (SELECT imageID FROM images WHERE type=’perm’ AND imageID BETWEEN ? and ?)”) to do this during dump. It was still incredibly slow, as it seemed the computer had to scan every single row, instead of jumping to the right row numbers as the inner query should return.

Comment: @IamAStudent - `IN ( SELECT ... )` is likely to be much slower than a `JOIN`.